# Virtualbox prevents Surface Pro 2 from sleeping/resuming from sleep

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, microsoft-surface

I have a new surface pro 2; installed virtualbox on it; it seems to prevent the surface pro from either sleeping or resuming from sleep (unclear which).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what happens when you attempt to place your tablet to sleep.  I assume you were able to do this before you install VirtualBox and if you were to uninstall VirtualBOx it would work again.

Comment: Yes, uninstalling made the problem go away; I guessed virtualbox was the problem as I had seen other people talk about changes to network interfaces causing problems and I know virtualbox adds one of these.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what happens when I put the tablet to sleep with virtualbox on. Essentially it appears to turn off (screen goes off) but if you try and turn the computer on again; it does not turn on. I can only seem to get it to turn on again by leaving it for a while, pressing and holding the on button for a while etc; I presume I am forcing it to re-boot somehow. Without virtualbox uninstalled; it just "works" and comes back on again after a couple of seconds.

Comment: You can configure the power settings on those virtual adapaters ( or you should be able to ) because Windows isn't entirely aware they are software based devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-install VirtualBox **without** bridged networking you should be fine - it worked for me.  This is a known issue with VirtualBox

> https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=56346&start=15

Comment: Your link is abbreviated and doesn't show the correct one. Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "install without bridged networking"?